# How do I obtain the RMSE from a QuantLib curve estimation?

Tags: programming, quantlib, yield-curve, term-structure

I'm estimating yield curves in Python using the QuantLib package and the included Nelson Siegel, Svensson, specifications. I can get the estimated parameters, but I would like to see a measure of the fit. So RMSE, MSE, or something like that...?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have actuals and estimates, you can always implement a custom performance metric. RMSE, RMSLE, MSE, etc.